# Unix- Sed replacing substring

Tags: unix, sed

I am new to `sed` . I want to replace a substring

for example:

```
var1=server1:game1,server2:game2,sever3:game1
```

output should be

```
server1 server2 server3 (with just spaces)
```

I have tried this.

```
echo $var1 | sed 's/,/ /g' | sed 's/:* / /g'
```

This is not working. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: You should quote variables like this `echo "$var1" | sed ..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this `sed`,

```
echo $var1 | sed 's/:[^,]\+,\?/ /g'
```

**Explanation:**

`:[^,]\+,` - It will match the string from `:` to `,`

`\?`       - Previous may occur or may not ( Since end of line don't have `,` )

Comment: thanks a lot, this suffice my purpose. could you please also help me understanding this :)

Comment: If you do not like the escaping, you can use this `sed -r 's/:[^,]+,?/ /g'`

Comment: Or with regular sed, this would probably be tight enough: `sed 's/:[^,]*,*/ /g'`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $var1 | sed s/:game[0-9],*/\ /
```

Assuming your sub string has `game` followed by a number(`[0-9]*`)

Answer (score 0):

An `awk` variation using same `regex` as `sed`

```
awk '{gsub(/:[^,]+,?/," ")}1' <<< "$var1"
```

PS Its always good custom to "quote" variables

Answer (score 0):

Just for info, you are really only matching, not replacing, so grep can be your friend (with -P):

```
grep -oP '[^:,=]+(?=:)'
```

That matches a number of characters that aren't `:,=` followed by a `:` using [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

This will put the servers on different lines, which may be what you want anyway. You can put them on one line by adding `tr`:

```
grep -oP '[^:,=]+(?=:)' | tr '\n' ' '
```

Comment: Note `-P` isn't supported in BSD grep. For BSD replace `-oP` with `-oE`.